# read_csv multi indexing dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have the following csv:

```
               value    value   value   value ...
id             1        1       1       2
indic          1        2       3       1
valuedate           
05/01/1970    1.0       2.0     3.2     5.2
06/01/1970    4.1       ...
07/01/1970          
08/01/1970
```

that I want to read in a pandas DataFrame, so I do the following:

```
df=pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv", skipinitialspace=True, tupleize_cols=True)
```

but get the following error:

> IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2

I suspect there might be an error with the multi indexing but I don't understand how to use the parameters of `read_csv` in order to solve this.
(NB: `valuedate` is the name of the index column)

I want to get this data into a DataFrame that would be multi-indexed: several indic sub columns under the id column.

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Answer (score 2):

**file.csv**:

```
               value    value   value   value
id             1        1       1       2
indic          1        2       3       1
valuedate           
05/01/1970    1.0       2.0     3.2     5.2
```

Do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", index_cols=0, delim_whitespace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
            value  value.1  value.2  value.3
id            1.0      1.0      1.0      2.0
indic         1.0      2.0      3.0      1.0
valuedate     NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
05/01/1970    1.0      2.0      3.2      5.2
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I want. But now Python throws the following error in a window: `Python has stop working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program.`. I guess it might have to do with the size of the CSV (1,326,055 KB) right ?